# Windows System State Analyzer 3.0 failing to compare file system snapshots

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-xp, filesystems, system-state

I have an issue with the Windows System State Analyzer 3.0.

The tool takes snapshots of the status of file systems, drivers, registry and services statuses, but when I try to compare those, it fails the file system comparison.

All the other types of comparisons work, but the file system one fails every single time.

This is a typical stack trace while attempting to compare file system (it fails also if the snapshots files are stored locally):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Logo\Software Certification Toolkit\Windows System State Analyzer>SAnalyzer.exe compare "\\ServerName\c$\Users\Public\Documents\Pre install.bin" "\\ServerName\c$\Users\Public\Documents\Post install.bin" /fa CompareResult.html
Comparing snapshot..........
Snapshot compare complete
Generating Report....C:\Users\Public\Documents\CompareResult.html
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range.
 Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.Analyzer.Utility.DirectoryStatistics.CountDirectoryModified()
   at Microsoft.Analyzer.Utility.DirectoryStatistics.SetDirectory()
   at Microsoft.Analyzer.Utility.ReportsHelper.CreateXmlFile(ComparisonObject comparisonObject)
   at Microsoft.Analyzer.Utility.ReportsHelper.GenerateReport(String xslPath, String htmlPath, ComparisonObject comparisonObject)
   at Microsoft.Analyzer.SnapShotTool.CommandLineSupport.GenerateReport(String htmlPath, ComparisonObject comparisonObject)
   at Microsoft.Analyzer.SnapShotTool.CommandLineSupport.CompareSnapShot(String[] CommandLineInfo)
   at Microsoft.Analyzer.SnapShotTool.SingletonApp.ProcessCommandLine(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Analyzer.SnapShotTool.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Searching on the web, Markus' last post in this thread is probably describing the root of this issue:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e9d3b3df-298b-4e6f-9058-6a3a94f86183/not-able-to-compare-using-windows-system-state-analyzer?forum=winserver2008appcompatabilityandcertification

I have tried to ask the Microsoft relevant team if they had plans to solve this issue, and release a new updated version of the tool, but their mailbox (WSLogoFB@Microsoft.com) doesn't work anymore.

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> ```
>  WSLogoFB@microsoft.com
> ```
>
> Technical details of permanent failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain
>   microsoft.com by microsoft-com.mail.protection.outlook.com.
>   [23.103.156.42].
>
> The error that the other server returned was: 550 5.4.1
>   [WSLogoFB@microsoft.com]: Recipient address rejected: Access denied

The comparison tool works for the registry, the services, the drivers, but not for the file system.

Both from the GUI and the user interface.

I tried the comparison on a number of OS, e.g. from Windows 2012 R2 to Windows 7, and I have also tried the Microsoft XP compatibility mode, to not avail.

I have used this tool extensively in the past, to certify applications on Windows Server 2008 R2, and it used to work without a glitch.

Any suggested work around?
Alternative suppliers?